# Git credentials in a shared virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, git

A friend and I want to use a (Ubuntu) VM to develop code. The main app is Visual Studio Code.

The idea of the VM is that it can guarantee that we both have the same versions of the same VS Code extensions, etc, guaranteeing an identical development environment.

We will use a shared directory which links to our Windows host (D:\shared) and mount that to an empty directory in the VM, so that while the VMs are identical (I create it and he gets a copy), we can each have our own code directories.

So far, so good, BUT, we want to be able to make Git pushes with our own individual credentials. What are our options?

- Can the git credentials be on a shared drive and fetched from outside of the VM ?  (preferable)
- failing that, can I delete my credentials from the VM before giving him a copy? If so, how? Less preferable, because I have to remember to do it each time I update the VM
- any other options?

I was planning on having a single shared user login for the VM. Perhaps I ought to have two, so that each can have its own credentials?

OR, since the code is own the HOST (each of our laptops), will the Git credentials also be with the code on our laptops, meaning no problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set git credentials on a per-folder basis, using the following commands:

```
git config --local user.email "yourmail@example.com"

git config --local user.name "yourName"
```

If I understand your situation correctly (you're using different directories in the same VM) this should solve your problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I am not sure if it is the answer, though. Both he & I might push to the same folder inside the VM. Coudl we have no git credentials inside the VVM (if so, how to remove the existing ones) and set them outside the VM and transfer them in via a shared directory?

Comment: Hey @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, TBH I would avoid using the same folder within the VM at all costs, this opens you up to a huge overwrite risk if you both open the same file, make edits and then subsequently save. Whoever saves last would overwrite the other person's change. This is specifically the problem git was invented to solve, and you'll be completely circumventing it by using the same folder. I think it's fine to use the same VM so your dev environments are the same, but writing to the same folder is definitely an anti-pattern! :) You could potentially implement file locking, but why? :)

Comment: See more thoughts on the matter in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168251/source-control-advice-across-multiple-developers-using-a-shared-folder